# Using the '.localhost' TLD searches in browsers instead of showing the site associated with the address

Tags: apache, dns, local, tld, loopback-address

According to [RFC 2606 (1999)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606) the TLD *.localhost* is reserved for use for testing locally.

The goal is to configure a preview site to run locally using the TLD .localhost, e.g. http://example.localhost

The problem is that when I use Chrome or Safari to access a '.localhost' TLD it searches google for example.localhost instead of treating it as a proper address. This is after configuring the *hosts* file to point back to `127.0.0.1`.

Am I misunderstanding the usage of this reserved TLD? Is there a way to configure this to work properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome browser doesn't like a domain with .loc TLD (for localhost domain testing) without http:// - how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877705/chrome-browser-doesnt-like-a-domain-with-loc-tld-for-localhost-domain-testing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.localhost` is not an existing, delegated TLD, which is why your browser doesn't find it.

What RFC 2606 says is that `.localhost` (along with `.test`, `.invalid` and `.example`) will never be a delegated TLD, so you can safely use that name for your own, local, purposes. That is, if you want to set up a private TLD for internal use, that TLD can be safely named `.localhost` without the risk of a future collision with a globally assigned name.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks. I understand now what the problem is.

Comment: The second part of the question is how to get it to work, though. Is it possible to set it up so that it works in all browsers on a local environment, or within a network?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `http://` first. Write `http://yolo.localhost` in your address bar and not `yolo.localhost`, then it will work.

See answers here for more information: [Chrome browser doesn't like a domain with .loc TLD (for localhost domain testing) without http:// - how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877705/chrome-browser-doesnt-like-a-domain-with-loc-tld-for-localhost-domain-testing)